# How do I iterate over rows in Pandas and check if the sum of each row is equal to the sum of a list?

Tags: pandas

I have tried:

```
for i, row in preferences.iterrows():
    if len(students_with_courses) == preferences.sum(axis = i):
```

But gets following error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use `a.empty`, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

I have tried:

```
for i, row in preferences.iterrows():
    if len(students_with_courses) == preferences.sum(axis = i):
```

But gets following error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use `a.empty`, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

Comment: what is `students_with_courses`? why do you iterate over the rows if you don't use `row`? Please provide a fully reproducible input/output example

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error you provided is that you are comparing is that `len(students_with_courses) == preferences.sum(axis = i)` returns a *series* containing `True`/`False` values, as opposed to one single `True`/`False` value. An `if` statement required one single `True`/`False` value.

To get to a working solution, I made some assumptions about what you mean by `students_with_courses` and `preferences`. I also assume you mean the *length* of the list, not the *sum* of the list since that's what your code shows.

```
students_with_courses = ["a", "b", "c"]
preferences = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [0, 1, 1, 3], 'column2': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'column3': [3, 6, 1, 8]})
```

If you're just looking to see if the sum of each row is equal to the length of your list, you can simplify to the code below instead of iterating over each row.

```
preferences.sum(axis=1) == len(students_with_courses)
```

This returns:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Note that if you want to compare the *sum* of the list instead of the *length* of the list, you can use the below code.

```
students_with_courses = [1, 0, 2]
preferences = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [0, 1, 1, 3], 'column2': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'column3': [3, 6, 1, 8]})
preferences.sum(axis=1) == sum(students_with_courses)
```

This returns:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```